# UFT opening browser with old session for IE Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, session, browser, qtp

I am automating a website where a user can login with different roles.But, after performing a operation with a specific roles when i am again opening the browser for another roles then UFT is opening browser with old session.

**Note**: This issue is occurring if i am running all the test cases in a suite. If i am running the scripts individually then it's working fine.

Moreover, I am also using a function to delete all the cookies and clear caches before opening the browser by using the command `"RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"`

Please help on this.

Comment: Does your web app that you are testing have a Logout function?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Browser.DeleteCookies` and/or `Browser.ClearCache`.

Comment: I am already deleting history using command "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"  Is it due to plugins that we check when UFT/QTP open first time?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application is saving your login details. If its saved in the browser, you could [try this](https://www.bu.edu/tech/services/support/desktop/software/troubleshooting/removing-password-from-browsers-saved-password-list/) (probably will need some code to do this). Once cleared, you should be able to launch your browser to the login page

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Could you include the pertinent points within this post? This will avoid issues where the link may become invalid.

Comment: I think the issue here might be autocomplete. Link in my answer shows how to delete autocomplete history for most browsers. I have found a tag here (autocomplete) that should shed more light on how you can either switch off or clear autocomplete for your browser programmatically (I found a post that talks about this but as I'm new here, I don't know how to tag that in this post). I think once that is switched off, when you launch your browser to display login page, it will allow you to then login with different credentials

Answer (score 0):

`ClearMyTracksByProcess` has a patchy support for various IE versions. Did you check whether the cookies were indeed deleted?

For IE, you have various option:

```
WebUtil.DeleteCookies
```

or as Motti pointed out

```
Browser("Google.com").DeleteCookies "Google"
Browser("Google.com").ClearCache
```

You may also want to have a look [at this article](http://www.learnqtp.com/how-to-delete-cookies-through-a-script/)  There are number of methods discussed on the article as well as in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

For apps having different roles may be logging out before entering another session is good idea as Trimble Epic pointed out. If you have a separate logging page then may be close that logging page you used to go to your web app portal so that session is completed or cleared. Usually, if same id's are used to log into web app and same time if your id is used in other application of your organization that might also cause the issue. I always used to forget to put log-out function on the end and used to get same issue time to time.